# Dimension of the sum of two vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

$\dim(U_1+U_2) = \dim U_1 +\dim U_2 - \dim(U_1\cap U_2).$

I want to make sure that my intuition is correct. Suppose we have two planes $U_1,U_2$ though the origin in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Since the planes meet at the origin, they also intersect, which in this case is a one-dimensional line in $\mathbb{R^3}$. To obtain the dimension of $U_1$ and $U_2$, we add the dimensions of the planes (4), and the subtract the dimensions of the line (1), which results in (3).

*additional question(s):

Can we generalize this notion to $\mathbb{F^{n}}$?

Suppose we have an additional case where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are planes in $\mathbb{R^3}$, but $U_1 \subseteq U_2$. In this instance, $dim(U_1 + U_2) < 3$, because the first two-dimensional plane is contained in the second and as a result, the dimensions of the subspaces when summed cannot exceed two. Since both subspaces $U_1,U_2$ are two dimensional and $U_1 \subseteq U_2$, then their intersection is also two-dimensional, concluding $dim(U_1+U_2)=2+2-2 = 2$.

Is this proper intuition?

Comment: The intuition is correct.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the latter case, they are actually the *same* plane, so their sum is again the same plane (as they are closed under addition).

Here is another (analogous) way to think about it. Let's start with a basis $B_0$ for $U_1\cap U_2.$ We can extend $B_0$ to a basis $B_1$ for $U_1$ and a basis $B_2$ for $U_2$. Then $B_1\cup B_2$ is a basis for $U_1+U_2,$ and $B_1\cap B_2=B_0,$ so $$\begin{align}\dim(U_1+U_2) &= |B_1\cup B_2|\\ &= |B_1|+|B_2|-|B_1\cap B_2|\\ &= |B_1|+|B_2|-|B_0|\\ &= \dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)-\dim(U_1\cap U_2).\end{align}$$ This generalizes nicely to $\Bbb F^n$, and allows us to avoid geometric arguments that may be less sensible for an arbitrary field $\Bbb F$.

Also, it will never be the case that the intersection of two planes in space is precisely $\{0\}.$ If there were two such planes $U_1$ and $U_2,$ then we would have $$\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)-\dim(U_1\cap U_2)=2+2-0=4>3=\dim(\Bbb R^3),$$ which is not possible, since $U_1+U_2$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could it be the case that a pair of two dimensional planes in $\mathbb{R^4}$ intersect at a point?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Consider $$U_1=\{(w,x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^4:y=z=0\}$$ and $$U_2=\{(w,x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^4:w=x=0\}.$$ The upshot in $\Bbb R^3$ is that there "isn't enough room" for two planar subspaces to avoid each other that well.

Comment: Why can we conclude that $B_{1} \cap B_{2} = B_{0}$? It seems perfectly reasonable that the extensions share vectors outside of $B_{0}$.

Comment: @Jonathan: If there is some $\vec v\in B_1\cap B_2,$ then $\vec v\in U_1\cap U_2.$ What then can we conclude by definition of $B_0$?

Comment: Ok, then $v$ must be a linear combination of $B_{0}$. But, this forces both $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ to be linearly dependent, right?

Comment: @Jonathan: If we further assume that $\vec v\notin B_0,$ yes. Otherwise, there's no problem.

Answer (score 18):

Cameron Buie's answer does answer the original question sufficiently. However, I'm adding the formal proof of the theorem in context (taken from "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler).

> If $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space then: $$\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim U_1 + \dim U_2 - \dim(U_1 \cap
>  U_2)$$

Let $u_1,...,u_m$ be a basis of $U_1\cap U_2$; thus $\dim (U_1\cap U_2)=m$. Because $u_1,...,u_m$ is a basis in $U_1\cap U_2$, it is linearly independent in $U_1$. Hence this list can be extended to a basis $u_1,...,u_m,v_1,...,v_j$ of $U_1$. Thus, $\dim U_1 = m+j$. Also extend $u_1,..,u_m$ to a basis $u_1,...,u_m, w_1,...,w_k$ of $U_2$. $\dim U_2 = m +k$.

We will show that $u_1,...,u_m,v_1,...,v_j,w_1,...,w_k$ is a basis of $U_1+U_2$. This will complete the proof because then we will have $$\dim(U_1+U_2)=m+j+k=\dim U_1 + \dim U_2 - \dim (U_1\cap U_2)$$

We just need to show that the list $u_1,...,u_m,v_1,...,v_j,w_1,...,w_k$ is linearly independent. To prove this, suppose:

$$a_1u_1+...+au_m+b_1v_1+...+b_jv_j+c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k=0$$

where all $a,b,c$'s are scalars. We need to show that all the $a,b$ and $c$'s are $0$.

The equation can be rewritten as

$$c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k=-a_1u_1 - ... -a_mu_m -b_1v_1 - ... - b_j v_j$$

Which shows that $c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k\in U_1$. But actually all $w$'s are in $U_2$. So the LHS must be an element of $U_1\cap U_2$.

$c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k=d_1u_1+...+d_mu_m$ for some choice of scalars $d_1,d_2,...,d_m$. But $u_1,...,u_m,w_1,...,w_k$ is linearly independent. So our last equation implies that all the $c$'s equal $0$.

Thus our original equation involving $a,b,c$ becomes

$$a_1u_1+...+a_mu_m+b_1v_1+...+b_jv_j=0$$

But we already knew that the list $u_1,...,u_m,v_1,...,v_j$ is linearly independent. This equation implies that all the $a$'s and $b$'s are $0$. We now know that all $a,b$ and $c$'s are $0$, hence proving our original claim.