# Can the intersection of two planes in 3-space be two points?

Tags: geometry

Of course the answer is no, but I need to prove it.
I tried contradiction, i.e. two different points that satisfy both equations, but I can't make much of that.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/500511/28900).

Comment: Are you looking for an analytic or geometric proof?

Answer (score 1):

No, the intersection of two convex sets must be convex.

Comment: This sounds very interesting and I happen to have seen the term convex while reading on my own, however I haven't yet been properly taught it, so I wouldn't know how to use it in a proof.

Answer (score 0):

I'll outline the proof
Get one point of intersection. Call it $A$
Calculate the cross product of the two normals. Call it $\vec v$
Show $A+\lambda\vec v$ satistifies both equation of the planes.

If you don't know how to calculate normal/cross product, get a second point of intersection $B$. Define $\vec v = B-A$

Comment: So basically, the proof is that if the intersection is even 1 point (or at least 1 point, however you want to phrase it), then it has to be a whole line?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, although the tutor proposed that we began the proof with exactly two points (which i suspect is the alternative proof you suggest, using B - A)

Comment: do you know about vectors? If not, I can add another elementary proof

Comment: yes, I know simple stuff like inner/cross product, vector equations of a line and a plane etc

Answer (score 0):

Given any plane in three space, and given any two distinct points $A$ and $B$ in the plane, the line through $A$ and $B$ must lie in the plane, as well. Thus, if $A$ and $B$ are in the intersection of two planes--meaning that $A$ and $B$ lie in both planes--then the line through $A$ and $B$ lies in both planes, so *every* point on that line is in the intersection of the two planes.