# Complements of a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum, dimension-theory-algebra

> Show that a non-trivial subspace $U$ of $V$ has two virtually disjoint complements iff $dim(U)\geq \frac{dim(V)}{2}$.

Definition 1:$S$ and $T$ are said to be virtually disjoint if $S\cap T=\{0\}$.

Definition 2: A subspace $T$ of $V$ is said to be complement of $S$ (a subspace of $V$) if $S\oplus T=V$ (i.e. $S+T$ is direct sum).

The **if** part is done, I am stuck with the **only if** part of the question. If possible try to find a suitable answer using Modular Law.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\geq$ or $\leq$?

Comment: @RobertShore, The question is right, it is $\geq$.

Comment: Then I must not know what you mean by a "complement."  Would you mind adding a definition of "complement" to the question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the only if, use the formula for the sum of subspaces, reported for example in [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283260/examples-of-dimvwdimv%E2%88%A9w-dimvdimw?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In fact, if $S,T$ are the disjoint complements, then
$$
dim(S) + dim(T) = dim(S + T) \le dim(V)
$$ 
but $dim(S) = dim(T) = dim(V) - dim(U)$ so 
$$
dim(U) = dim(V) - dim(S) \ge dim(V) - \frac{\dim(V)}2= \frac{\dim(V)}2.
$$

Comment: I was using this formula for the **only if** part but I was stuck. Kindly post the solution or provide some hints.

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty edited