# Prove that $\dim(N(A|B)) = \dim(N(A)) + \dim(N(B)) + \dim(R(A) \cap R(B))$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ be a $m \times k$ matrix. Let $N(A),N(B),R(A),R(B)$ be the nullspace of $A$, the nullspace of $B$, the range of $A$, and the range of $B$, respectively. Prove that
$$\dim(N(A|B)) = \dim(N(A)) + \dim(N(B)) + \dim(R(A) \cap R(B))$$

Any idea to solve it? Thanks for help in advanced.

Comment: what $N(A|B)$ denots ?

Comment: Idk, I guess it denotes the augmented matrix of both.

Comment: anyone can help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see something like $\dim N(A)$, you know that “rank-nullity” is lurking.

What does this say in your case? You have three matrices, so you can say

1. $\dim R(A)+\dim N(A)=n$
2. $\dim R(B)+\dim N(B)=k$
3. $\dim R(A|B)+\dim N(A|B)=n+k$

Thus what you want to prove can be rewritten as
$$
n+k-\dim R(A|B)=n-\dim R(A)+k-\dim R(B)+\dim\bigl(R(A)\cap R(B)\bigr)
$$
which becomes
$$
\dim R(A|B)=\dim R(A)+\dim R(B)-\dim\bigl(R(A)\cap R(B)\bigr)
$$
Can you link $R(A|B)$ with $R(A)$ and $R(B)$ and apply another well-known result?

Comment: i dont know how can $R(A|B) = R(A) + R(B)$ hold.

Comment: @arnold Just apply the definition: $R(A)$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ generated by the columns of $A$.

Comment: if I take $x \in R(A|B)$, what I can got?

Comment: so, $R(A|B)$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ generated by the columns of $A|B$?

Comment: @arnold Yes, so…

Comment: so, $R(A|B)$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ generated by columns of $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: then, $R(A|B) = R(A) + R(B)$?

Comment: @arnold Yes, that's it.

Comment: Wow, great. I can feel the sense. Thanks!

Comment: So, from that, I can prove $dim(R(A|B)) = dim(R(A))+dim(R(B))-dim(R(A) \cap R(B))$?

Comment: @arnold Don't you know about Grassmann's formula?

Answer (score 0):

Treat $A,B, A|B$ as linear map form $R^n, R^k, R^{n+k}$ respectively to $R^m$.

By rank-nullity, the equality is

$(n+k)-dim(R(A|B)) = n-dim(R(A)) + k-dim(R(B)) + dim(R(A) \cap R(B))$

$dim(R(A|B)) = dim(R(A)) + dim(R(B)) - dim(R(A) \cap R(B))$

If we prove $R(A|B)=R(A)+R(B)$, the equality is equvalent to dimension fomula of $R(A)+R(B)$: $dim(R(A)+R(B)) = dim(R(A)) + dim(R(B)) - dim(R(A) \cap R(B))$

This formula is true, you can see:[Dimension of the sum of two vector subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500511/dimension-of-the-sum-of-two-vector-subspaces)

Here is the rest of the proof($R(A|B)=R(A)+R(B)$):

For $x \in R(A)+R(B)$, there exist $v_a,v_b$  s.t.  $x=Av_a+Bv_b$.

Let $v$ be (n+k)-vector with first n slots $v_a$ and last k slot $v_b$.

Then $x=(A|B)v \in R(A|B)$

Similarly, $x\in R(A|B)$, then $x=(A|B)v $ for some v.

Let $v_a$ be first n slots of v, $v_b$ be last k slots of v. Then $x=Av_a+Bv_b\in R(A)+R(B)$.

[image]

Comment: sorry, what is $n$ and $k$?

Comment: n, k are size of matrix you indicate

Comment: is $dim(R(A) \cap R(B))$ must be 0?

Comment: no it can be anything

Comment: but, why we only prove that $R(A|B)=R(A)+R(B)$ ?

Comment: I just edit a bit. They are both subspace of $R^m$. Then we can apply dimension fomula to prove

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107497/discussion-between-mira-from-earth-and-arnold).

Comment: i still confusing on your proof

Comment: Which part then?

Comment: on the word "let v be (n+k)-vector..." and then

Comment: v is a vector with (n+k) slots, $v=(v_a^T|v_b^T)^T$

Comment: what does $v_a$ and $v_b$ mean?

Comment: "For $x \in R(A)+R(B)$, there exist $v_a,v_b$  s.t.  $x=Av_a+Bv_b$. " and "Let $v_a$ be first n slots of v, $v_b$ be last k slots of v. Then $x=Av_a+Bv_b\in R(A)+R(B)$. " I did define them, and first one exist by definition of rank space