# Proof of rank inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, self-learning, matrix-rank

In *Titu Andreescu's Essential Linear Algebra: a problem solving approach* I faced the following questions:

[image]

How do I prove the underlined relation? I tried direct element chasing but then the relation seems trivial. If $\mathrm{Im}(T_1)+\mathrm{Im}(T_2)$ consists of all the elements of the form $Y_1+Y_2$ with $Y_1 \in \mathrm{Im}(T_1), Y_2 \in \mathrm{Im}(T_2)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(T_1+T_2)$ consists of those $Y$ for which $\exists X\in V: Y=(T_1+T_2)(X)=T_1(X)+T_2(X)$ but here $T_1(X)\in\mathrm{Im}(T_1)$ and $T_2(X)\in\mathrm{Im}(T_2)$ so if we follow this line of thought they should be equivalent. I cannot find my mistake.

And for number $2$ how do we get there? I tried finding information about the subadditivity of $\mathrm{dim}$ but didn't find anything.

[image]

Here in the end it says that we only used the injectivity of $S_1$ and the surjectivity of $S_2$. However I feel like we actually used the surjectivity of $S_1$ to prove that $S_1(U)=V$ (number $1$ in the picture) and the biijectivity of $S_2$ to conclude that the two spaces have the same dimension (number $2$ in the picture). Is there a flaw in my reasoning or is this a typo?

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: It seems that the second question in the first picture is actually Grassman's formula which is described in an earlier chapter of the book, so we are done with that.

Answer (score 2):

The image of $T_1+T_2$ consists of all vectors of the form $(T_1+T_2)v = T_1v + T_2v,$ which are of course contained in the set $\text{im }T_1 + \text{im }T_2 = \{T_1v + T_2w \mid v, w \in V\}.$

However, this inclusion may be proper. This is because the image of $T_1+T_2$ might not include a vector like $T_1v + T_2w.$ For instance, if $T_1(v) = v$ and $T_2(v) = -v,$ then $T_1+T_2$ is the zero map, but $T_1, T_2$ each have image $V,$ so the sum of their images is $V.$

Answer (score 1):

$T_1 v + T_2 w$ is an element of $\text{Im}(T_1) + \text{Im}(T_2)$, but might not be in $\text{Im}(T_1 + T_2)$ when $v \ne w$.

For the dimension inequality, note that [$\dim(U+V) = \dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U \cap V)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500511/dimension-of-the-sum-of-two-vector-subspaces) in general.

---

For your second question, you are correct that bijectivity of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are necessary.

Example to show that "$S_1$ is injective and $S_2$ is surjective" is not enough: Suppose $S_1 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is injective and $S_2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is surjective, and $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is the identity. Then $\text{rank}(T)=2$ while $S_2 T S_1 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has rank at most $1$.

---

Response to comment: I now realize that the author probably meant "injectivity of $S_2$ and surjectivity of $S_1$." You have already noted that for $S_1$ only only surjectivity was used. For $S_2$, note that injectivity is sufficient to justify "$(TS_1)(U)$ and $S_2 ((T S_1)(U))$ are isomorphic." Here, $S_2$ is mapping a subspace of $W$ to a subspace of $Z$, and it is not necessary for $S_2$ to map $W$ onto all of $Z$.

Comment: In your example the biijectivity of both maps is indeed necessary and I see how it is used, but in the proof of the book I still cannot see the where the necessity of the injectivity of $S_1$ is used (I see the surjectivity is used for the equality number $1$).

Comment: @Summand See my update

Comment: You said: For S2, note that injectivity is sufficient to justify "$(TS_1)(U)$ and $S_2((TS_1)(U))$ are isomorphic."
However doesn't injectivity only guarantee that $\mathrm{dim}((TS_1)(U)) \leq \mathrm{dim}(S_2((TS_1)(U)))$? I feel like surjectivity is also necessary but I wanna confirm.

Comment: @Summand Yes. The general statement is "if $S : V \to W$ is an injective linear map, then $S$ is an isomorphism between $V$ and its image $S(V)$." (If $S$ is surjective then $S(V)=W$. If $S$ is not surjective, then $S(V)$ is a strict subspace of $W$.) You can probably prove this by working with a basis or something.