# Rank of partitioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

According to some textbooks, for a $n \times p$ partitioned matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 & X_2 \end{bmatrix}$, where $n > p$, the following holds.

$$ \operatorname{rank}(X) = \operatorname{rank}(X_1) + \operatorname{rank}(X_2) - \dim(\operatorname{col}(X_1) \cap \operatorname{col}(X_2)) $$

where $\operatorname{col} (A)$ denotes the column space of $A$. I want to have the result $\operatorname{rank}(X) = \operatorname{rank} (X_1) + \operatorname{rank} (X_2)$. For this, I need to prove that

$$\dim(\operatorname{col} (X_1) \cap \text{col} (X_2)) = 0$$

but I don't know how to prove this in a specific matrix. How can I prove $\operatorname{col}(X_1) \cap \operatorname{col}(X_2) = \emptyset$? Does $X_1 a \neq X_2 b$ for any nozero $a$ and $b$ prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, you need to prove that $\operatorname{col}(X_1) \cap \operatorname{col}(X_2) = 0$, not $\emptyset$. And yes, this is implied by $X_1 a \ne X_2 b$ for $a, b \ne 0$, since every nonzero element of $\operatorname{col}(X_1)$ is given by $X_1a $ for some $a \ne 0$ and similarly for $X_2$.

If you are unsure where the rank formula comes from, it's just the formula for the dimension of the sum of two subspaces (see eg [Dimension of the sum of two vector subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500511/dimension-of-the-sum-of-two-vector-subspaces))
$$\dim(U + V) = \dim U + \dim V - \dim (U \cap V)$$
applied to $\operatorname{col}(X) = \operatorname{col}(X_1) + \operatorname{col}(X_2)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: @user0131 Happy to help! Since you seem to have a few questions without accepted  answers, you should know that upvoting ▲ and, once you have a definitive solution, [accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) ✔ answers are good ways to say thanks; these actions signal resolution, prevent the page from being bumped, score points, and influence the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes. It also increases the chances of your future questions being answered.